What exactly is Fresnel distance?
I've been trying to understand fresnel distance with fraunhoffer diffraction in mind. As far as I understand it's the distance from the slit at which the effects of diffraction is next to zero . For which the width of the central maxima which comprises maximum intensity of the light must be the same as the width of the slit. In my course the given formula is z = (slit width)^2 / (lambda) . But when I work it out I'm getting twice the answer . Is something wrong with my definition of fresnel distance or is my course wrong? I did it as shown in the image

